# Mysql regex alphanumerical with some special chars

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Alright, I've had a some nightmares with it already so i bow my stupid head to the almighty hive-mind of the Stackoverflow.

UPD: the parameters of my task have been changed. I need to find the codes that could include special chars like parentheses (), and/or @, #, &, $.

So the codes could look like:

> "A", "Bb", "2C8", "A7(BO)19", B29H$, 29H(6JI)0# etc

The problem is that all these codes are optional. I've tried like Barmar (see reply 1) suggested, but slightly modifing the MySQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column REGEXP '^[a-z0-9\@\#\$\&()]*$' 
AND column LIKE CONCAT('%', '$v', '%')
```

It cannot return me "S(LJ)9" or "09S(LJ)3$" if i seek for "SLJ" or "S(LJ)"

Well, aside some real important nucleotide sequence in my DNA that would allow me to use brains more efficiently (or have them), what am i missing in this regex or the query itself? 
Thanks anyone in advance.

Comment: Are the characters the user inputs __required__ to be in the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column REGEXP '^[a-z0-9()]*$' /* code contains alphanumerics and parentheses */
AND column NOT REGEXP '[0-9]{3}' /* code does not contain >2 digits in a row */
AND column LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') /* code contains the user input */
```

where ? is bound with the user input (you should be using PDO or mysqli prepared statements).

Comment: Thanks, Barmar! The user can input up to 5 codes and they can be randomly met in 5 cols. The logic is to find rows where all the codes could be found in any of the specific columns: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN(SELECT ID FROM table WHERE (((col0 REGEXP '^[\w()]*$' AND col0 LIKE CONCAT('%', '$v', '%'))OR ... OR(col4 REGEXP '^[\w()]*$' AND col4 LIKE CONCAT('%', '$v', '%')))AND ... AND((col0 REGEXP '^[\w()]*$' AND col0 LIKE CONCAT('%', '$v5', '%'))OR ... OR(col4 REGEXP '^[\w()]*$' AND col4 LIKE CONCAT('%', '$v5', '%')))) and othercol is NOT null)` It sadly returns nothing

Comment: Mysql doesn't have `\w` and `\d` regexp escape sequences, I've changed my answer to expand these. Try this form.

Comment: Thanks again, Barmar. After the last update of your solution it works good enough. Sadly the project im working with is very sensitive to such search in the db. I will try to master the art of regex :)